# How do you narrow down a promise function that is inside and array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, promise

For a project that I am working on, I need to use 7 promise functions to get data from an API. I have the promise functions returning an array of data as shown below.

```
                var json1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    fetch(url[0])
                    .then(r => {
                        resolve(r.json())
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        reject(err)
                    })
                })
                var json2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

                    fetch(url[1])
                    .then(r => {
                        resolve(r.json())
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        reject(err)
                    })
                })
                //code is repeated with different links until json7
            return [json1,json2,json3,json4,json5,json6,json7];
```

I can get to the single promise data using...

```
const data = await fetchURL(urlToQuery())
var dataBP = data[0];
```

However, I can not narrow down the JSON in this Promise data. I previously used `dataBP[0].Wind_Speed` to get the data, but it comes back `undefined`.

Here is a sample of the JSON that I am working with.

```
  {
    "Wind_Speed": "9.0",
    "Air_Temp": "3.7",
    "Solar_Energy": "0.0",
    "Low_Air_Temp": "3.7",
    "Dew_Point": "2.0",
    "Solar_Rad": "0.0",
    "Rain_Rate": "0.0",
    "Rel_Humidity": "89.0",
    "Atm_Pres": "28.348",
    "Station_ID": "Buckingham Point",
    "DateTime_UTC": "2019-12-26 16:15:00",
    "Hi_Wind_Speed": "12.0",
    "Wind_Dir": "NW",
    "Rain": "0.0",
    "Hi_Wind_Speed_Dir": "WSW",
    "Hi_Air_Temp": "3.9"
  }
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: *Is your promise already done by the time you call the variable?* In fact, just a question that might give you a little advice.

Comment: @k3llydev Yes. I'm pretty sure it is finished.

Comment: The thing is that I don't see any callback against your fetch method to start using the variable when the promise is solved.

Comment: classic example of the Promise constructor antipattern.

Comment: `return Promise.all(url.map(u => fetch(u).then(r => r.json())));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is `Promise.all` like:

```
Promise.all(arrayOfPromises).then((values) => {
  //Here you can access the values/properties
  values[0].Wind_Speed
})
```

Take into account that in this case if any promise in the array is rejected the `.all` will not hit the `.then` bull will hit a `.catch`.

For a comprehensive explanation go: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: What would the ```Promise.all``` replace?

Comment: The promise functions in the array return to the ```data``` constant.

Comment: @wiebecoding you could return the promise array and leave the function as-is. However, to unpack the results you need to yield the function result to the `Promise.all`.

Comment: I have the promise function working, but I cant seem to return it to the call function. I have ```function(values) {console.log(values);});``` but when i put in ```return values```, it does not return it to the calling function of ```const data = await fetchURL(urlToQuery())```. What do I need to add?

Comment: Could you send over a gist with the rest of the code? That way I could tell you where's the place you could unpack the promises.